# CSS - How to set margin-left dynamically with a fixed value

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want a div's margin left value = 50% of parent div - 300px.

So, what I have done is-

```
<img id="layer2" style="
      display: block;
      margin-left: 50%-300px;
      width: 300px;" >
```

But it is not working.

I also have tried-

```
margin-left: 300px-50%;
```

It is also not working.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: use `margin-left:calc(50% - 300px)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `margin-left: calc(50% - 300px);`. But it working from IE

Answer (score 1):

What I like to do in cases like this is to mix padding and margin. If the total space on the left you need is 50% - 300px, then you could do something like this:

```
 padding-left: 50%; // Padding can't be negative
 margin-left: -300px;
```

If you're doing a border or something that will make padding not work, then simply add another div around your current one, with the above styling.